# SELECT MAX of COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, count, max

I have a table "well". It contains a column app_rate_unit (type: nvarchar).
My goal is to count every distinct value in the table and let the DBMS (MS Server 2005) give me the most occurring one.

This is my code:

```
SELECT MAX(app_rate_unit) AS MAX_APP
  FROM (SELECT app_rate_unit, COUNT(*) AS co
          FROM dbo.well AS w
         GROUP BY app_rate_unit
        ) AS derivedtbl_1
```

The poblem with it is however, that my DBMS actually delivers the lowest count to me.

SideQuestion: How do I filter for a foreign key (in the table) and NOT NULL (in app_rate_unit) when counting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select top 1 app_rate_unit, count(*) from dbo.well
group by app_rate_unit
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: what if there are more than one rows having same max of count, then how should we write a query that will select all the top rows having max of counts instead of only selecting top 1?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(app_rate_unit)AS MAX_APP , 
        app_rate_unit 
    FROM 
        dbo.well
    WHERE
            app_rate_unit IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        app_rate_unit 
    ORDER BY 
            MAX_APP DESC
```

The above script will give you the count and the item. You can change the count if you are not sure only one item will have the maximum number of occurrence.

Comment: works like a charm. how come it doesn't count the NULL values but stb's statement does?

Comment: may be because NULL is not greater than any other value.
But I have added the NULL checking condition explicitly. Check the edited script.

Comment: he got the "where" condition in it. Anyways, i don't know why Rain is using two selects, he just needs one

Comment: @stb: Because I could not apply MAX and Count in the same query.It gave an error. Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. If possible please let me know how to write that using single SELECT.

Comment: You dont use a MAX aggregation in your query. Have a look at my statement, it does exactly the same as yours and does only use one select.

Comment: @stb - Not quite the same. It would be the same if your query had a where clause filtering out null app_rate_unit values. I prefer your (stb) version, with or without the filter.

Comment: @dbenham yes i know, but its not in connection with the statement structure itself, just an additional thingy

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 count(*) as co from dbo.well as w group by app_rate_unit
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Works, but i don't want the count-value, but the name of the value, that occurred the most. Do you have any input regarding the SideQuestion i did pose?

Comment: I think he wants to get the app_rate_unit with the highest count, not the count itself. Have a look at my statement.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL we can write query which using max of count as

```
select max(count) from (

select count(id) from Table _name group by created_by,status_id having status_id = 6 ) as Alias
```

eg

```
select max(count) from (

select count(id) from orders group by created_by,status_id having status_id = 6 ) as foo
```