# SQL Server MAX of a COUNT in a group

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

So I've been having problems with my SQL code below (I'm still new to SQL, so I'm probably doing it wrong). Right now I want to be able to count how many times an Emp_ID appears next to a Cust_ID and then only show the Emp_ID that appears the most.

```
Temp table #RAttP 

|CUST_ID | EMP_NAME | EMP_ID | SOMETHING1 | SOMETHING2 |
|:------:|:--------:|:------:|:----------:|:----------:|
| 1      |   John   |   100  |     w/e    |     w/e    |
| 1      |   John   |   100  |     w/e    |     w/e    |
| 1      |   Jane   |   200  |     w/e    |     w/e    |
| 2      |   Jane   |   200  |     w/e    |     w/e    |
```

Answer I'm looking for:

```
|CUST_ID | EMP_NAME | EMP_ID |
|:------:|:--------:|:------:|
| 1      |   John   |   100  | 
| 2      |   Jane   |   200  |
```

And my code:

```
SELECT FL2.CUST_ID
       ,#RAttP.EMP_NAME
       ,#RAttP.EMP_ID
       ,FL2.MostSeen
    FROM #RAttP
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT FL1.CUST_ID
               ,MAX(FL1.AmtSeen) AS MostSeen
            FROM (SELECT #RAttP.CUST_ID
                   ,#RAttP.EMP_NAME
                   ,#RAttP.EMP_ID
                   ,COUNT(EMP_ID) AS AmtSeen
                        FROM #RAttP
                        GROUP BY #RAttP.CUST_ID, #RAttP.EMP_NAME, #RAttP.EMP_ID
                 ) FL1
            GROUP BY FL1.CUST_ID
        )FL2
        ON FL2.CUST_ID = #RAttP.CUST_ID
    GROUP BY FL2.MostSeen, FL2.CUST_ID, #RAttP.EMP_NAME, #RAttP.EMP_ID
    ORDER BY FL2.CUST_ID
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand your requirement. Are you sure that the sample data is meaningful? The answer you're looking for does not even contain the `MostSeen` column from your query.

Comment: order by FL2.CUST_ID, count(*)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT MAX of COUNT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646401/select-max-of-count)

Comment: @TabAlleman - No even close to OP's requirement

Comment: Interesting, I went by the question in the subject line, but I don't see what the desired result has to do with counting at all.  Now this question is simply unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function for that:

```
SELECT CUST_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_ID
FROM (
  SELECT CUST_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_ID, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT CUST_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_ID,
         COUNT(EMP_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID, EMP_ID) AS cnt
    FROM RAttP ) AS t) AS s
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

`COUNT` used with an `OVER` clause on a `CUST_ID, EMP_ID` partition, returns the number of times an `Emp_ID` appears next to a `Cust_ID`. The second-level query used this count in the `OVER` clause of a `ROW_NUMBER` window function, so as to determine the record having the maximum number of `Emp_ID` appearances.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution to your problem:

```
SELECT          * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT          *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rank
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT          cust_id, emp_id, count(1) as cnt
        FROM            #RAttP
        GROUP BY        cust_id, emp_id
    ) AS a
) AS B 
WHERE b.rank=1
```