# Order Users with more registry in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get in order the users who have more records in another table.

For example:

```
Tb_users
ID - user - email
1 - user1 - user1@hotmail.com
2 - user2 - user2@hotmail.com

Tb_registry
ID - registry - usersID
1 - registry - 2
2 - registry - 2
3 - registry - 2
4 - registry - 1
5 - registry - 1
```

I need to get in order those who have the highest number of records in the tb_registry records

```
ID 2 user2 (3 records)
ID 1 user1 (2 records)
```

Thanks!
Regards!

Comment: I hope that help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646401/select-max-of-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
Select Tb_users.ID, Tb_users.user, count(*) as [Record_Count]
FROM Tb_users
JOIN Tb_registry on Tb_users.ID = Tb_registry.usersID
GROUP BY Tb_users.ID, Tb_users.user
ORDER BY [Record_Count] desc
```

Let me know if you have any issues and I'll review the answer. I don't have a dataset handy to verify the answer.